# JsRender/JsViews performance issue in Edge and IE

Tags: javascript, web-worker, jsrender, jsviews

```js
const N_COLS = 20; // use it to modify the number of columns
const N_ROWS = 20; // use it to modify the number of rows

const data = {
  name: "Sample",
  columns: generateColumns(N_COLS),
  rows: generateRows(N_ROWS),
}

function generateColumns(n){
  let columns = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    columns.push({ index: i, name : "Column " + i})
  }
  return columns;
}

function generateRows(n){
  let rows = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    rows.push({ index: i, fields: generateFields(N_COLS)});
  }
  return rows;
}

function generateFields(n){
    let fields = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        fields.push({index: i, text: "Field " + i});
    }
    return fields;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.time('Compile');
    var tmpl = $.templates("#mainTemplate");
    console.timeEnd('Compile');

    console.time('Render');
    tmpl.link("#container", data);
    console.timeEnd('Render');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <h1>{{:name}}</h1>
            {{include tmpl="#contentTemplate"/}}
        </script>

        <script id="contentTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    {{for columns}}
                        {{include tmpl="#columnTemplate"/}}
                    {{/for}}
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {{for rows}}
                        {{include tmpl="#rowTemplate"/}}
                    {{/for}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                
        </script>
        
        <!-- In this example, using those templates with an include tag doesn't make sense, but that's because it's a simplified version of what I'm working with -->
        <!-- In my scenario having those templates separated is a must have :( -->
        <script id="columnTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <th>{{:name}}</th>
        </script>
        
        <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <tr>
                {{for fields}}
                    {{include tmpl="#fieldTemplate"/}}
                {{/for}}
            </tr>
        </script>

        <script id="fieldTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <td>
                {{:text}}
            </td>
        </script>

        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm facing a performance issue with JsViews in Edge and IE. I've got a really big template which has so many include tags in it and so many data-links as well. In Chrome and Firefox, performance it's okay, it takes less than 1 second to render which is good for my needs, but in Edge and IE, it takes almost 5 seconds :(

This template could be used as many times as we want in a given page, so performance issue is incremental in here.

I've tried using JsRender instead of JsViews, adapting my templates and objects without data-links because I've noticed that, in my scenario, using them impacts performance so much, in Chrome and Firefox I achieved 500ms at rendering and in IE and Edge.. 2 seconds, which still being so much for my needs.

I already tried to simplify the templates I'm using, but I've reached the bottom line..

I've got many ideas to try to solve this problem, and here is where my questions comes from:

- Is there (or would it be in new JsViews/JsRender versions) a way to compile templates in a web worker? I know that in a web worker we can't use JQuery, access DOM nor use objects with custom prototypes, but who knows..
  Even if the compile time would be the same, at least I would be able to compile
  templates in paralel.
- Are there some magic tips to improve JsViews/JsRender performance in IE and Edge? (throwing away IE and Edge would be nice, but unfortunately it's not an option :( xD)

PS: I 'm afraid I can't post any sort of code because I'm talking about a project for the enterprise I'm working for.

Comment: Did you do any profiling analysis as to where the slowness is ocurring? Template compilation should only happen on initial page load, so if you are triggering a new compilation of the templates, or sub-templates, on every call, that is an error. Any template should only be compiled once. Does profiling show that the issue includes re-compiling? If not, pre-compiliation won't help much....

Comment: @BorisMoore templates are compiled once for sure. I’ve noticed that I made a mistake in my web worker’s question, I wanted to say “render on a web worker” not compiling ^^’

Comment: JsRender does not need jQuery (see http://jsviews.com/#jsr-quickstart). Nor does it need the DOM to render. (It renders to an HTML markup string). But JsViews (and data-linking) does need jQuery and a DOM. To understand your perf issues, you might want to show examples of the coding style, or create a sample/jsfiddle that illustrates the perf issue, even if you don't show specific code from your project.

Comment: @BorisMoore I’ve got an additional issue using JsRender in a Web Worker, I use custom prototypes, and I can’t figure a way to send my objects to it. I understand this is not a JsRender issue so let it be, I’ll find a way to solve that :p. However, as soon as I can I’ll update my question with a jsfiddle to give you an approach of my scenario, may be my templates or objects can be redefined to boost perf, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @BorisMoore I've updated my question with a simple jsfiddle trying to show what I'm working with. If you run it on chrome you' ll notice it takes an average of 50ms to compile and render, but in edge it takes almost 200ms (at least in my computer). In my real scenario this diference is even bigger because templates and objects are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

IE and Edge are quite a lot slower than Chrome - though how much will depend on details of code and scenario. For example IE is much slower than Chrome in some HTML table rendering scenarios. You may find that avoiding table layouts and instead using CSS for equivalent grid layouts, you get a big perf improvement - and it may be more marked in IE and Edge....

If you look at this http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/test/perf-compare.html in different browsers, you will see that IE can be much slower, and not only for JsRender, but equally for other components or template engines.

Apart from avoiding HTML tables (if that is possible) you can consider replacing:

```
{{for columns}}
  {{include tmpl="#columnTemplate"/}}
{{/for}}
```

by

```
{{for columns tmpl="#columnTemplate"/}}
```

if that is possible for you.

Also, a small improvement might come from:

```
{{... tmpl=~columnTemplate/}}
```

and providing the compiled templates as helpers, as in

```
var tmpls = {
    columnTemplate: $.templates("#columnTemplate"),
    ...
};

tmpl.link("#container", data, tmpls);
```

Also, if you are not using the JsViews data-linking at all (I notice all your tags are `{{...}}`, not `{^{...}}`) then you can do tmpl.render(...) and then insert the HTML in the DOM in one go...

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I think the only thing I can try it's, as you say, getting rid of tables and use a custom CSS solution because in my real scenario I already provide the compiled templates as helpers and use the one line for/include. I also avoided using data-linking because in Edge it was very painful in wich performance refers to (didn't noticed I was using tmpl.link in my jsfiddle example, sorry for that ^^'). Anyway, thank you for time :)